# Can't Display null with second column in datagridview, from 2 tables

Tags: vb.net

```
#i have two tables buyers table and sales table#
```

buyers table

---

|buyer | balance|

sales table
 |buyer | sales|buydate|

I have tried the following select query

```
Dim connection As OleDbConnection  
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter  
Dim ds As New DataSet  
Dim SQLStr As String  
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand  
connection = New  
OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=consignacion.mdb;")    
SQLStr = "SELECT b.buyer as [Buyer],b.balance as 
[Balance],SUM(s.total) as [Sales],  
b.balance+SUM(s.total) as [Total] From buyerdb b  
INNER Join salesdb s on b.buyer=s.buyer  
WHERE s.total Is Not NULL And  
s.buydate =@buydate And  
s.total<>@sales AND  
b.balance> @balance  
GROUP By b.buyer,b.balance"  
SQLStr = "SELECT b.buyer as [Buyer],b.balance as 
[Balance],SUM(s.total) as [Sales],  
b.balance+SUM(s.total) as [Total] From buyerdb b  
INNER Join salesdb s on b.buyer=s.buyer  
WHERE s.total Is Not NULL And  
s.buydate =@buydate And s.total<>@sales AND b.balance> @balance  
GROUP By b.buyer,b.balance"  
cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQLStr, connection)  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buydate", Form1.Lbldate2.Text)  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", 0)  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales", "")
```

> ```
>    I expect the output to be  
>
>   buyer   balance  sales   total
>   CESS    350 984 1334
>   DARWIN  0 345 345
>   GLEN    1000 4334 5334
>   GLENDA  0 170 170
>   JOSE    1000 2240 3240
>   LITO    0 120 120
>   LOUIE   0 280 280
>   TANIS   0 2250 2250
>   YOLLY   1500 832 2332
>   michael 1500 [null/norecor] 1500
>   Dudice   700 [null/norecord] 700
>
>
>     but the output is
> ```
>
> buyer   balance  sales   total

```
    CESS      350      84      334    
>    DARWIN 0   345 345    
>    GLEN   1000    4334    5334    
>    GLENDA 0   170 170    
>    JOSE   1000    2240    3240    
>    LITO   0   120 120    
>    LOUIE  0   280 280    
>    TANIS  0   2250    2250    
>    YOLLY  1500    832 2332
```

> **it is not displaying buyers with balance but no recorded sales on the given buydate**

i have tried everything i know. i even search google and youtube and seems can't get the right output on my data grid view.

Answer (score 0):

If i asked you to show me something that didn't exist, you couldn't because it doesn't exist. It's the same with NULLS in databases. They signify that something doesn't exist, so it's impossible for the database to show you nothing.

What you can do is use the ISNULL statement to replace the NULLS with an actual value. Try changing your select statement like this:

```
SELECT b.buyer as [Buyer],b.balance as 
[Balance],SUM(ISNULL(s.total,0)) as [Sales] .........
```

This will replace all NULLS in s.total with a value of 0.

Comment: i am having wrong argument error. if i replace it with sum(isnull(s.total,0)